# Default JDK in Android Studio is JRE

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to change the JDK path in Android Studio. But when I went to settings I found a path to JRE "`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`". Is this correct or should I change it with the downloaded jdk from oracle? I know JDK should contain JRE but I never heard of it the other way around.

[image]

I don't know if Android Studio works in its current configuration (because I am learning to use it)

Comment: You should be all good with the defaults.

Comment: A question on different topic: is there a difference between "SDK platform" and the images for AVD? When I download an API version from SDK Manager shouldn't I see the corresponding image when creating a new virtual device?

Comment: You do need to download images separately, as they're quite large (a gig or more each I think).  You can do this through the SDK manager preferences.

Comment: Sorry one last question: "The API level of the target device is important, because your app won't be able to run on a system image with an API level that's less than that required by your app"(https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).  But if my app uses 4.4 KitKat and AVD is way higher(latest android) will it work? I am short on memory and I can't test this theory.

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Long answer: Android apps will (almost) always be forward-compatible. So if you build for API 16 and want to run on an API 29 device, you'll be ok.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration is perfectly valid. This `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` **contains** the jdk (for some reason...) that comes bundled with Android Studio. You should be fine with the current configurations.

Comment: Is this the default path? because Gradle keeps giving me this warning "Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal while using Android Studio."